# Изменение значения на странице от 0 до n

Tags: javascript, jquery

При определенных изменениях формы значение в поле `<label>` должно меняться от `0` до `n`.

Пробую в цикле:

```
var val1 = 255;    
for (var i = 0; i <= val1; i++) {
    $("label").html("$" + i);   
};
```

В итоге браузер задерживается на долю секунды, а затем выдает конечное число в `<label>`.

Comment: ..а это к чему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так происходит, потому, что сначала выполняется весь JavaScript, и только после его выполнения «микрофон передаётся» браузеру, чтобы отрисовать то, что есть. Чтобы показывать промежуточные значения, надо почаще давать пас браузеру – на каждое очередное значение переменной. Например, как вам [предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/465169/7161) @Igor.

Но раз **уже используется jQuery**, можно решить задачу её родным методом [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). К тому же, красиво – с плавным стартом и замедлением в конце:

```
function labelUpdate(p){ $('label').text('$' + Math.round(p))}
$({price: 0}).animate({price: 255}, {step: labelUpdate, duration: 12000});
```

Продолжительность анимации задаётся свойством `duration` в миллисекундах. Для равномерной анимации можно указать доп. `easing: 'linear'` во втором аргументе метода `animate()`.

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/cv5bz4aL/).

Comment: Да! Это именно то, что мне нужно было! Я первый раз в жизни вижу такой вариант использования jquery.animate! Думал придется это самому реализовывать!

Answer (score 3):

Плотный цикл не дает браузеру возможности отрисовать изменения. Создадим idle состояние между изменениями html:

```
function UpdateLabel() {
  $("label").html("$" + (iter++));
  if (iter <= val1)
    setTimeout(UpdateLabel, 100);
}

var val1 = 255;    
var iter = 0;

UpdateLabel();
```

Comment: Отлично! Это работает! Спасибо